# ¿Cine Callao o Cines Callao?

Tags: gramática, plurales, nombres-propios

Quisiera confirmar con ustedes si es Cine Callao o Cines Callao y por qué es el uno y no el otro (No sé si es una expresión correcta). Según Wikipedia, es “[Cine Callao](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cine_Callao)”, pero en el sitio web de ese edificio pone “[Cines Callao](https://cinescallao.es/)”. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El nombre de una empresa es decisión de la empresa (y no tiene que seguir ninguna regla lingüística), y en este caso es "Cines Callao". En nombres de cines, el uso del plural parece ser tan común como el del singular, [al menos en Madrid](https://www.google.com/maps/search/cine+madrid/@40.4185126,-3.7057529,14z). El plural hace pensar que es un cine grande o una cadena de cines, mientras que el singular puede hacerlo parecer más "único" o "alternativo".

Sin embargo, en el habla cotidiana, uno suele decir "voy al cine", y por tanto diría también "voy al cine de Callao". Dado que se va a un único sitio, decir "voy a los Cines Callao" suena algo más forzado, casi como si se quisiera hacer publicidad de la empresa. La diferencia es pequeña, y ninguna de las dos maneras de decirlo es incorrecta.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Answer (score 4):

La explicación es sencilla: originalmente era una única sala de proyección de películas de cine: "Cine Callao", en un edificio con el mismo nombre.

Actualmente (desde 1998) hay dos salas de proyección, y de ahí la forma plural "Cines Callao", que están ubicados en el edificio ["Cine Callao"](https://callaocitylights.es/conoce-callao-city-lights/).

Answer (score 0):

---

Que tal?

Ante la cuestión, ¿es Cine Callao o Cines Callao?.

Aclarar simplemente que cuando una entidad posee varios negocios que pertenecen a un mismo dueño ó empresa, se suele poner en plural el objeto de negocio y el nombre ó apellido del mismo se mantiene normalmente intacto.
Cines Callao, significa simplemente que existe más de un cine, también podría ocurrir, que no suele ser el caso, que tengan varias salas en el mismo local.
Lo mismo podría ocurrir, por ejemplo, con Hamburgueserías Rodríguez, Ferreterías Pérez ó Papelerías López.

P.D. Una vez me preguntaron, si en estos cines debía estar uno siempre en silencio, sin poder hablar.

Espero te haya ayudado. Saludos. Diego M.